# computing precision and recall based on two list of bounding box

Tags: python, object-detection

does anyone know, given two lists of the bounding box, one is predicted, the other is the ground truth, is there some **existing python library or code** I can use to compute the accuracy? There are many existing codes for first calculating the lou, and I know I can compute it on my own. But I thought there should also be some existing tools I can use to directly get the accuracy indexes so that I finish my project in a smarter way than coding by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the Help Center before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a lot of love `from sklearn.metrics`

Heres a link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics

Here's a basic example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
pr_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(pr_score)
```

Where y_pred is the predictions and y_test is the so called "ground truth"

In the above link you can read and chose the evaluation metric that suits you.